# Creating a unique index on already existing data in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I am attempting to add a UNIQUE INDEX to a table in sqlite. The table already has data and the fields I am using for the index have duplicate values. Will I be able to add the index? Will a partial index be created?

Comment: I actually tried this in SQLite Manager for firefox, with the following result. Adding the index did not return any error messages, but also did not allow duplicates. Inserting a duplicate did not return an error message, but also didn't insert the duplicate. Creating the index after having duplicate data did not return any error messages, but duplicates were still possible to insert.

Comment: Also there is no mention of this particular situation anywhere in the documentarion for the CREATE INDEX command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will fail:

```
$ sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-06-02 21:00:34
sqlite> create table t(x);
sqlite> insert into t values (1), (1);
sqlite> create unique index ui on t(x);
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: t.x
```

Comment: Suggest any solution ?

Comment: @Yatix It is not possible to create a unique constraint on non-unique data (this is the whole point of a constraint). Either change the data in the column so that it is unique, or do not create the constraint.